# Are seed phrases universal?

Tags: security

I was recently using metamask, an ether wallet, when i noticed something weird.  Upon installation, I attempted to import an external wallet using a seed phrase.  I was told, according to the app, it was a success, however, the public and private address' were different than the foreign wallet's addresses - not a success.  However, when I attempted to use a seed phrase associated with a different metamask wallet the importing into a new metamask wallet was truly successful.  Are seed phrases universal, or just useful within a particular app?

Comment: What external wallet? You may have a derivation path issue. Especially if your external wallet is a Ledger, derivation path have to be selected the right way.

Comment: The external wallet was atomic wallet...what does it matter?

Comment: I wouldn't trust it. Use the private key exported from Atomic instead: https://www.reddit.com/r/atomicwallet/comments/dmhmbl/hello_i_just_would_like_to_ask_if_i_can_import_a/

Comment: The foreign wallet was imported correctly when using the public address, but not the seed phrase

Answer (score 1):

There is standard [BIP 0039](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) that defines the word list and how to obtain the master key from the mnemonic phrase. Usually it is combined with [BIP 0044](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) to create separate keys for each cryptocurrencies.

In theory applications that follows those standard should generate the same addresses from the mnemonic.